# How to create a multi array in nested loop

Tags: python, arrays, ontology

I don't understand to create a multi array in nested loop.
Here's my output code:

```
for row in qres:
  for r in row:
     print(r.replace('http://www.semanticweb.org/aalviian/ontologies/2017/1/untitled-ontology-10#',''))
```

Here's my data output:

```
bercak_daun
fungus_crassicarpa
daun
bercak coklat
bercak kecil atau besar
bercak_daun_gejala

hawar_daun
fungus_crassicarpa
daun
bercak coklat
bercak kecil
hawar_daun_gejala
```

Here's my array expectation:

```
[['bercak daun','fungus_crassicarpa','daun','bercak coklat','bercak kecil atau besar','bercak_daun_gejala'],['hawar_daun','fungus_crassicarpa','daun','bercak coklat','bercak kecil','hawar_daun_gejala']]
```

How to create t my array expectation ? I'm newbie in python.

Comment: You can insert elements to an array using `.append()` method.

Comment: But this is my result after using append method.


['bercak_daun', 'fungus_crassicarpa', 'daun', 'bercak coklat', 'bercak kecil atau besar', 'bercak_daun_gejala',  'hawar_daun', 'fungus_crassicarpa', 'daun', 'bercak coklat', 'bercak kecil', 'hawar_daun_gejala'] with np shape (12,) and i want (2,6) for size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an empty list. Add sub-list for each qres. Append each element in `t[-1]`. Print `t` at the end, outside of the loop.

Try this (can't run it so there might be an error):

```
t = []
for row in qres:
    t.append([])
    for r in row:
        t[-1].append(r.replace('http://www.semanticweb.org/aalviian/ontologies/2017/1/untitled-ontology-10#',''))
print t
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It's Solved :)